# FullCalendar: On mouseover, how do I tell top left corner of event hovered over?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar v1.5.3 by Adam Shaw.  I've gotten almost everything to work with it accept I am trying to do a "simple" hovertip and can't quite get what I'm looking for.

I am trying to get the left side of my tooltip to be the same as the left side of the event I'm hovering over.  And I'm trying to get the tooltip to hover above the event.

The code I am currently using appears to give me a "random" left and top of where the mouse entered the FullCalendar event.

My current code looks like:

```
    eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            var eventInfo = $("#EventInfoTip");
            var mousex = jsEvent.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
            var mousey = jsEvent.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
            var tipWidth = eventInfo.width(); //Find width of tooltip
            var tipHeight = eventInfo.height(); //Find height of tooltip

            //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
            var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
            //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
            var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

            if (tipVisX < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
                mousex = jsEvent.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
            } if (tipVisY < 20) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
                mousey = jsEvent.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
            }
            //Absolute position the tooltip according to mouse position
            eventInfo.css({ top: mousey, left: mousex });
            eventInfo.show(); //Show tool tip
        } //end full calendar mouseover event
```

EventInfoTip is a simple span on the page:

```
<span id = "EventInfoTip">
I'm over an event
</span>
```

Is it possible to get the top and left of the current event I'm hovering over?

Comment: dont know if this will help, therefore as a comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs:" Within the callback function, `this` is set to the event's div" element.

So you can use $(this).offset() to get the event div location in page.

```
var elOffset= $(this).offset(), offsetLeft=elOffset.left,  offsetTop=elOffset.top
```

Comment: Offset was what I'm looking for.  My code above is a little off now but this has me going down the right path.

Comment: if you are using `angularjs` or any other js framework apart from `jquery`, the `this` keyword will reference the `window` instead of the `div` element, in this case, (if you are willing to edit the plugin), just assign the `this` keyword to another `param` of the `eventMouseover` trigger

Comment: @MuhiaNJoroge your comment makes no sense. The context of `this` is clearly defined here

Comment: @charletfl, i know the `this` keyword if defined but the context is lost and is never passed along when you use angular. if you try `this` your callback within angular, it will mean something else, the `window`. try it your self. read this http://luizfar.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/dont-use-this-in-javascript/

Comment: @MuhiaNJoroge I am quite familiar with angular but without knowing how you are using your code can be of no help. STart a new question with full details.

Comment: @charlietfl it was not a question, i was suggesting for those that might get in trouble with the `this` keyword can just assign `this` to a new variable and pass it to the `eventMouseover` trigger as a new param, what dont you get

Comment: @charlietfl i am no way down voting your answer, i used the tip there, but `$(this)` will not be the element it will be a new object within the angular scope.

Comment: @MuhiaNJoroge if it is used inside the same event handler here, no it won't. You are over generalizing. The documents for this plugin are very clear